# See Cambodian translation in Facebook

Tags: facebook, localization

I am Australian but through my son's marriage I now have family in Cambodia.
It seems to be the only language without translation on Facebook.

Can Cambodian interface be enabled on Facebook?

Comment: You can go directly to it using this link: https://km-kh.facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Under Settings -> Language I see Khmer language among the options (selected on the screenshot). It's found near the end of the list.

[image: Khmer]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Facebook home page : https://www.facebook.com/, and check if your language is given or not. To check the language click on plus sign in downside of page (see below screenshot). If you find it, select that language, all the Facebook content will show in that language:

[image]